# Is there a way to access options for multiple graphql mutations with @apollo/react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a multipart form that registers data twice. I use two mutations in my component so it looks something like this.

```
const [register, { loading }] = useMutation(REGISTER),
      [tags, { loading }] = useMutation(TAGS);
```

This obviously doesn't work though as I can't have two loading variables. I've been trying to find a workaround for the scenario but haven't come upon anything successful.

If it was a query I know I could do something like:

```
const register = useQuery(REGISTER),
      tags = useQuery(TAGS);

// now I have register.loading && tags.loading
```

But I haven't found a similar case with useMutation because if I have something like:

```
const register = useMutation(REGISTER);

register({var: "something"})
  .then(res => {  });
```

Then there's no promise and it throws an error.

Is there a better practice for handling this type of instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply rename the variable when you are destructuring (reference: 
https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming/)

so your code will look like:

```
const [register, { loading: registerLoading }] = useMutation(REGISTER),
const [tags, { loading: tagsLoading }] = useMutation(TAGS);
```

Comment: interesting. I had tried that but the other way around.. [register, { registerLoading: loading } ] . Guess I just had things backwards, thanks!

Comment: sure please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: gotchu! just wanted to make sure it was correct. thanks again!